# remove display property from bootstrap using jquery in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have a text block with content-editable true so my problem is that this content is wrapped in label tag and bootstrap gave label tag display inline-block property so that property make internet explorer haslayout property true so that why it take double click to edit with an ugly border.

I can't remove label tag or modify bootstrap css so only option is left is either override css or use some jquery/javascript trick so when i tried override css but that not solve my problem then i read this in this blog

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

> The display-property differs: while 'inline-block' sets haslayout = true, the flag will not be reset to false later on by overriding the value with 'block' or 'inline' in another rule set.

So only option left is use jquery to remove display property but i can't find anywhere how can i remove display property that is given using element not inline so how to remove display property using jquery??

check this fiddle in IE. In this i include bootstrap css in this and it take double click to edit in ie

[https://jsfiddle.net/csrdfrL4/](https://jsfiddle.net/csrdfrL4/3/)

```
<div class="container" contenteditable="true">
<label>
    <div class="item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: you can add a new class name to the label to override the display property. such as `label.custom-Label{display:none;}` and add this class `<label class='custom-Label'>....`

Comment: using this i can override display property but the problem is with when haslayout set to true with previous display it can't set false again so only way to do is remove previous display property other wise it doesn't work i have update the fiddle check in ie

Comment: If you add the `contenteditable="true"` to `<div class="item" contenteditable="true">` instead, you don't need to dbl-click to edit.

Comment: i can't because i make this example with shorter code but in my website in container there are other elements too that are editable and its hard to give every element content-editable true